# How to insert a new value without going through prompt

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my code, in fact I want to insert new values in my
`while` loop without prompt. It would be easier with prompt and alert messages but this is not the exercise that was asked of me is different.

If I do not know a new value my number of hit automatically goes to 0 because it finds it in an infinite loop taking the - 1 without change of value.

Instruction of TP:

Write an XHTML page of the following game. The user must guess a number between 1 and 100 chosen
randomly by the computer. The user gives the number of shots allowed and starts the game at
using a button. With each proposal, the message displayed in the page changes, "bigger", "more
little "," bravo, you won in shots "and" lost, the number was x ".

```js
function jouer()          
{    
        //Initialisation   
        var nbCoupsAut = document.getElementById("nbCoupsAut").value;  
        var nbPropose = document.getElementById("nbPropose").value;                
        var nbMystere = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);       
  document.getElementById("nbEssais").innerHTML = ("Vous devez trouver en " + nbCoupsAut + " coups maximum ");  
          
        while(nbPropose != nbMystere && nbCoupsAut != 0)     
  {    
   /*Trouver un moyen d'insérer une nouvelle valeur pour pas que ca boucle !!!!*/  
   
   
   var nbMystere = 30;        
   if(nbPropose < 1) //Nombre trop petit 
   { 
    document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = (+ nbPropose + " Votre nombre est trop petit !");  
    continue; 
   }
   if(nbPropose > 100) //Nombre trop grand 
   {  
    document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = (+ nbPropose + " Votre est nombre trop grand !");    
    continue; 
   }
   if(nbPropose < nbMystere) //C'est plus !  
   {
    document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = ("Trop petit !");  
    nbCoupsAut--;  
    
    continue; 
    
   }
   if(nbPropose > nbMystere) //C'est moins !  
   {
    document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = ("Trop grand!");   
    nbCoupsAut--;          
    continue; 
      
   }
 
   if(nbCoupsAut == 0)          
   {
    document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = ("Perdu, le nombre mystère était "+ nbMystere);   
    break; 
   } 
   if(nbPropose == nbMystere) //Gagné !   
   { 
    document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = ("Bravo le nombre mystère était "+ nbMystere); 
    break;  
   }
  
        }
         
}

</script>
```

```html
<div><center>
<h2>Trouvez un nombre entre 1 et 100</h2>

<p>Nombre de coups autorisé </p>  
<input type="number" id="nbCoupsAut" value="nbCoupsAut" required></p> 
   
<button id="jouer" onclick="jouer()">Jouer</button>  
 
      
<p>Proposez un nombre</p>  
<input type="number" id="nbPropose" value="nbPropose" required></p>   
 
  
<p id="nbEssais"></p>      
<p id="nbMystere" value="nbMystere"></p>     
</center></div> 
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have great difficulties to understand what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is - could you try to rephrase your question please?

Comment: Use form control elements like `input type="text"` to get the input, and an HTMLElement, ex. `p` to show the results. Then, instea of `while` loop, add a button with a click listener to check the results. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

Comment: `<input type="number" min="1" required>` should be enough, no?

Comment: I wrote a working example, but you were close!

Answer (score 0):

The properties `min`, `max` and `value` in the `input-number` work fine.

And default values if user enters nothing.

```js
  function jouer()          
  {    

    // get the value, with defaults
   
    var nbCoupsAut = document.getElementById("nbCoupsAut").value || 1 ;  
    var nbPropose = document.getElementById("nbPropose").value || 1 ;

    // Search for a "Nombre mystère"
            
    var nbMystere = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    // A message to user to inform him about the number of attempts
    // Like "You have only <nbCoupsAut> attempts"

   document.getElementById("nbEssais").innerHTML = ("Vous devez trouver en " + nbCoupsAut + " coups maximum ");
          
     // Loop while user don't find the number myster and
     // number of attemps is not enough

     while ( nbPropose != nbMystere && nbCoupsAut != 0)     
     { 
   
    //var nbMystere = 30;


    if(nbPropose < 1) //Nombre trop petit 
    { 
          // Now, this section is never reached

      document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = (+ nbPropose + " Votre nombre est trop petit !");  
     continue; 
    }
        

    if(nbPropose > 100) //Nombre trop grand 
    {  

          // Now this section is never reached

     document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = (+ nbPropose + " Votre est nombre trop grand !");    
     continue; 
    }
    if(nbPropose < nbMystere) //C'est plus !  
    {
     document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = ("Trop petit !");  
     nbCoupsAut--;  
    
     continue;   
    }
     if(nbPropose > nbMystere) //C'est moins !  
     {
      document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = ("Trop grand!");   
      nbCoupsAut--;          
      continue; 
      
     }
 
     if(nbCoupsAut == 0)          
     {
      document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = ("Perdu, le nombre mystère était "+ nbMystere);   
      break; 
     } 
     if(nbPropose == nbMystere) //Gagné !   
     { 
      document.getElementById("nbMystere").innerHTML = ("Bravo le nombre mystère était "+ nbMystere); 
      break;  
     }
  
          }
         
  }
```

```html
<div><center>
<h2>Trouvez un nombre entre 1 et 100</h2>

<p>Nombre de coups autorisé </p>  

<!--

   We add a min value (min) and a default value (value)

   -->

<input type="number" id="nbCoupsAut" value="nbCoupsAut" min='1' value="1" required></p> 
   
<button id="jouer" onclick="jouer()">Jouer</button>  
 
      
<p>Proposez un nombre</p>  
<!--

   We add a min value (min), a max value (max) and a default 
   value (value)

   -->

<input type="number" id="nbPropose" value="nbPropose" min="1" max="100" value="1" required></p>   
  
<p id="nbEssais"></p>      
<p id="nbMystere" value="nbMystere"></p>     
</center></div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help is nice, but when I put for example 5 shots allowed I should receive a message that alert me that I lost it does not work..